# This PHP for loop is limited to two iterations but there are three arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

This is the pattern I'm hoping to achieve:

0 => 6 => "not checked"

Where 0 increments, 6 is arbitrary, "not checked" is arbitrary

I can see why there are three, the outputted set of arrays, there are three $arrray()'s which are shown by $array(3) but what I don't understand is that the for loop limits the loop to two runs. From 0 to 1, so why are there three and not two? I see the two "not checked". What is up with the first one?

I'm not grasping multi-dimensional arrays too well.

So I have this:

```
<?php

// $array = [][]; this is not correct
$array = [[]]; // original to get output below
$b = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
  $array[][$i] = "not checked";
}

var_dump($array);

?>
```

Which outputs:

```
array(3) { 
  [0]=> array(0) {
    // blank
  } 
  [1]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> string(11) "not checked" 
  } 
  [2]=> array(1) {
    [1]=> string(11) "not checked" 
  } 
}
```

**Current working code**

```
<?php

for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
  $array[][$i] = "not checked";
}

var_dump($array);

?>
```

Output:

```
array(2) { 
  [0]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> string(11) "not checked" 
  } 
  [1]=> array(1) { 
    [1]=> string(11) "not checked" 
  } 
}
```

Comment: `$array = [][];` -> error, let me guess it's `$array[] = [];`; problem found

Comment: This also creates the first element in the array, which is obviously empty: `$array = [][];`

Comment: @arkascha The only thing that creates is an error.

Comment: @Rizier123 what error? Is it the declaration inside the for loop or the top outside of the for loop?

Comment: @Rizier123 Indeed, you are right. Then probably that is not the exact code the OP is using.

Comment: @janicehoplin Add [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and look.

Comment: @Rizier, I changed the top to be $array[ ] = [ ]; but there is still the first empty array. This also works: $array = [ [ ] ];

Comment: Sure, since you actually _create_ that element with that command. Just use that, if you really need to initialize that variable: `$array = [];`.

Comment: @arkascha that was perfect. I removed the top line and just kept the $array[ ][ $i ] = "not checked"; now there are only two arrays inside the main array.

Comment: @janicehoplin And we can *close the loop* and come back to my guess from 10 minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253123/this-php-for-loop-is-limited-to-two-iterations-but-there-are-three-arrays#comment60135964_36253123

Comment: Yeah I just removed the first top $array "declaration?" outside of the for loop.

Comment: @janicehoplin You don't freaking have this line `$array = [][];` in your code, otherwise you question would look different. You have/had `$array[] = [];` (Just do a few Ctrl + Z in your editor) and you will see it. You add an empty array into the first element with `$array[] = [];` and **what you wanted to write is:** `$array = [];`, which is initializing your variable as empty array.

Comment: @Rizier123, I don't get what you're saying. The line $array = [ ] [ ] is still up there. I've corrected it on my editor based on what you guys had said which lead to removing that declaration and just leaving the $array[ ][ $i ] =  "not checked"; inside the for loop. Will show difference/current code above.

Comment: What he is trying to say is: if you really were using `$array = [][];` then you would have gotten an error, the code would not have created any array at all, you would have gotten no output at all.

Comment: @arkascha I see. I may have actually mistyped that. I had $array = [ [ ] ]; which seemed to work as well.

Comment: Yes, indeed that would have produced the result you got. And now you can explain the "why" yourself :-)

Comment: @Rizier123, I see what you're saying. I ran it as the original and you're right it's a white page.

Comment: In such case you should _always_ take a look at your http servers error log file. That is where you can actually read what exactly is wrong and where the error is.

Comment: @arkascha, that's not something that's quickly visbile on web console / on the page right? I'd have to actually view the logs via SSH or FTP?

Comment: You could turn on error output, but that is a horrible thing, since it breaks your page layout and often is really hard to read if _parts_ of your page is created and mixed with the error output. There are also approaches to pump the php error message into a JS scnippet, so that the message can be seen in the browsers console, but that is far to complicated for debugging. You indeed should always monitor that log file which is why people typically develop with a local http server. You could however simply mount the remote log folder to your local system via fuse/ssh. Easy and elegant.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beautiful part of PHP is array and string manipulation. if you really want to you can start with `$a = array();` but you can just do something like:

```
<?php
    $a[0][6] = "not checked";
    var_dump($a);
?>
```

I assume there is a greater pattern you're trying to map. But if you want the first to increment then just put `$i` in the 1st dimension. But as others have pointed you're declaration isn't quite correct. The `array()` function initializes arrays, not `[][]`;

Comment: Thanks for this, they answered the question above but I will also mark this as an answer because it accomplishes what I was asking for. Yes I am trying to use it to map something greater.